# Mover div a la derecha

Tags: html, css

Primero quiero aclarar que soy nuevo en esto, así que disculpen el formato de la pregunta. Me gustaría mover mi DIV con clase "Menu" a la derecha y no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, aquí les dejo mi código.

```
<body>
   <div> 
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <nav>
                    <span><a href="#">Mission</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Locations</a></span>
               </nav>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que el div menu se vea a la derecha del div con la clase logo es tan fácil como añadir float:left en logo:

```css
.logo {float:left;}
```

```html
<body>
   <div> 
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <nav>
                    <span><a href="#">Mission</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Locations</a></span>
               </nav>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Listo amigo :)

```css
<style>
.header {
  display: flex;
  
}

.menu {
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="img/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy Logo" />
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
        <nav>
          <span><a href="#">Mission</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></span>
          <span><a href="#">Locations</a></span>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia amigo, eso lo puedes realizar aplicacndo una sencilla clase en css a continuacion te dejo la linea de codigo.

```
.menu{text-align: right;}
```

Aplica en siguiente estilo en tu CSS y listo tu grupo (div) se alineara a la derecha.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head><style type="html/css">
       .menu{
       text-align: right;
       }
    </style></head>
 <body>
   <div> 
    <!-- Header -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="Tea Cozy Logo" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <nav>
                    <span><a href="#">Mission</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Locations</a></span>
               </nav>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>    
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: hmm si (no te olvides la comilla despues de style type="text/css")

Comment: ¿Cómo funciona este código? Lee [answer].

Comment: xd en html pe..

Comment: @LuisFerEcheandiaSami lo que te comenta padaleiana es que idealmente debes explicar el código que expones, una respuesta con contexto es de mayor ayuda que una que solo tiene un script

Comment: La pregunta no fue en qué lenguaje está el código ;)